# Transfering my arduino/TI-MSP430 Launchpad/Energia skills to real world projects and C

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, stm32, msp430

I'm learning electronics/microcontroller programming through TI-MSP430 Launchpad(Energia) and Arduino.

Both are based on wiring framework, and very good place to start for a beginner like me.

Now as I'm forwarding in my learning, I'm thinking to explore more and want to do a real world project. My project can be easily done on both above mentioned platforms, but I want to use STM8S-Discovery(Dev board or STM8S series MCU) for this but there is no wiring framework for STM8S as far as I know and I don't want to use if there is any.

What other skills/information I need to migrate from these wiring framework based platform to real world microcontroller projects?

Thanks in advance for inputs!

Comment: why stm8 and not stm32?  Define what you mean by "wiring framework" and what st is lacking that ti and atmel or others have?

Comment: you have stm32 tagged on this question, the stm8 has absolutely nothing to do with the stm32 other than they both come from st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet and user's guide will be your best friend. Be sure to look at programming examples for that device as well. Typically you'll need to do the following:

1. Initialize clock system and setup peripherals and I/O. (Frameworks generally do all this for you). Read some of the actual code behind the scenes of Energia to see how it actually works.
2. Once the main hardware is initialized, setup your business logic (variables).
3. Loop indefinitely (like most embedded systems do)... while (true) anyone?

I hope that helps.

I contributed the A110LR09 Booster Pack library for Energia. Take a look at the source code if you're interested with how to write specific device drivers in C/C++ for the MSP430.